# Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to `float'

Tags: input, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RightMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxSpeed = 10f;
    bool facingRight = true;

    void Start() {}

    void FixedUpdate() {

        float move = (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0); 
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

This is the full error I keep getting:

> Assets/Scripts/RightMovement.cs(14,23): error CS0029: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type `bool' to`float'

I want to use `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` to move my sprite character, but I only want him to move right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0` is a Boolean (true/false) value which will be true if the return value from `GetAxis` is greater than zero, or false otherwise. That's why it's complaining about trying to shoehorn a Boolean into a float variable.

It sounds like you want to force it to be non-negative only, in which case there are two likely possibilities.

---

The first is to ensure that negative values are translated to zero and that would involve something like:

```
float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
if (move < 0) move = 0;
```

or, if you're the sort that prefers one-liners:

```
float move = Math.Max(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
```

---

The second would be to translate negative to the equivalent positive, something like:

```
float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
if (move < 0) move = -move;
```

or, again, a one-liner:

```
float move = Math.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
```

---

I suspect the former is probably what you're after but you should think about what you want negative values turned in to, and adjust to that.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I'VE BEEN TRYING TO FIX THIS FOR WEEKS

Comment: @Abaseen, glad I could help. Though any problem that can't be fixed in a few hours should be put up on to SO while you continue to nut it out. That way, thousands of people work on it side-by-side :-)